# Makefile: what's the name of this warning?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I'm compiling a 3rd party .c file.

I've no intention to modify the source code. I'm not a .c programmer. And the code is not mine.

> EDIT: This is the folder code I need to compile, for the precision, I need only magiskboot; it's a specific piece of a more large tool. The official makefile build all the tool with the
>   result that the specific executable I want has something 'wrong'. So
>   I'm just trying to build it standalone
>
> [link to magiskboot specific directory on github](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/tree/master/core/jni/magiskboot)

I've this warning when compiling using gcc

```
../include/utils.h:89:37: warning: ‘struct ucred’ declared inside parameter list
void get_client_cred(int fd, struct ucred *cred);
```

What's the name of this type of warning? And how to suppress it?

I searched into https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html but without founding the right flag

Comment: This is a vanilla C compilation error - it's unrelated to makefiles.

Comment: It has nothing to do with makefiles.

Comment: It's nothing to do with make.

Comment: How to suppress a warning? By fixing what it tells you.

Comment: "what's the name of this warning?" - what does that even mean? Do warnings have names now? Why do you care what its name is?

Comment: The downvotes are quite hard, I think. It seems like the OP just wants to add the `-Wno-…` flag to CFLAGS and doesn't know which one

Comment: @xanoetux does that mean "ignore warnings"?

Comment: Although this is not good style of course; but that was not the question

Comment: @xanoetux just supressing compiler warnings is rarely the answer. You want to *fix* them.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl just supressing compiler warnings is not a good solution - nobody said so -, but the OP mentioned he isn't able to or at least doesn't want to change the code (and gave n code, making any diagnosis quite hard). And, by the way, I think there could be a `-Wno-all` flag, but I've to check that.

Comment: @xanoetux If there *is* a "-Wno-all" flag or similar and anyone actually uses it, then they should not be allowed near a serious code-base and should go back to their basic programming books. Compiler warnings are there for a *reason*. They catch *errors*. You *should* enable as many of them as you can (and fix them). Ignoring them just labels you, right then and there, as a greenhorn or incompetent. Please stay away from any code *I'm* responsible for.

Comment: Just to clarify, my projects are all compiled with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`, so I understand the importance of compiler warnings. But if the OP was questioned to, e.g., setup a completely silent make process, and has no coding experience or time, this is what to do.

Comment: @JesperJuhl in this case OP is not the author of the code. They just compile the code, and if the task is to compile someone else's code, ignoring warnings could be a feasible strategy.

Comment: @SergeyA I see what you are saying but I don't agree. Ignoring warnings and still incorporating the code into your project seems very questionable to me. I hope most people strive for higher standards (but I'm probably wrong since there's so much crap "out there").

Comment: This is just a WAG, but the closest thing I can find in the gcc documentation is `-Wno-missing-declarations`

Comment: @JesperJuhl I used to compile a lot of open source code. Regretfully, many applications come with a hefty does of warnings. What was I to do? I didn't have resources to study the application and fix the warning. Instead, I had to use whatever I had.

Comment: @SergeyA we are probably in different situations. But in *my* case, I wouldn't use any code that caused trivial compiler warnings. And if someone told me I *had to* I would plain refuse until I had studied the code (and probably submitted a few fixes upstream) - doing anything less would be unprofessional. As for your "What was I to do?" Question; I'd say "just say no". Don't just accept crap - there's too much of that going on already.

Comment: @DOUGLAS O. MOEN - Excuse me, but if your codebase generated 25k warnings, then it was probably crap and you *should* have fixed those warnings instead of ignoring them. There probably were *real bugs* hiding there.

Comment: @JesperJuhl nobody told me to, it is just that I need this application and there was no prebuilt package. Fixing application wasn't an option, not using the application would mean my goals are not achieved. Needs must.

Comment: 'most' provided code will compile with NO warnings.  if you get a warning like the one mentioned in the question, then most likely there is a missing header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not appear to be a command line flag to suppress just this warning. (Going by the [gcc source code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/c/c-decl.c#L7342) which is passing 0 for the second argument to `warning_at`.) You can add `-w` to suppress all warnings. If the code is actually C++, which is unlikely but possible, using g++ instead of gcc might fix the issue. (I'd expect lots else to be wrong if the code was originally written as C++.)

Answer (score 2):

Move your struct declaration so that it comes before the function declarations. I know you don't want to edit the 3rd party source, but that is how you fix this warning.

Comment: The warning does not say it is undeclared.

Comment: @Weather Vane: Yes, it is actually does say that implicitly. Otherwise, there wouldn't be any warning.

Comment: @AnT if it was unknown the warning would say that **explicitly**? I took the warning to mean there is a conflict: but without the MCVE the answer is guesswork

Comment: @Weather Vane: The warning basically says: "You are declaring a *new* struct type with *prototype scope*. It won't be visible outside of that scope". If the struct type were already known at that point, the reference to it woudn't have been regarded as a new declaration.

Comment: @AnT a curious session: MSVC does not object to that function prototype, nor to a function definition which just has `return`, and not even when calling that function from `main` with `get_client_cred(0, NULL);` Is there a reason for that (apart from the vagaries of MSVC)?

Comment: @WeatherVane: The warning says, in effect, that `struct ucred` was not *previously* declared. Declaring `struct ucred *cred` as a parameter is perfectly legal whether `struct ucred` was previously declared or not. But if it wasn't previously declared, then it's pretty much useless, since it refers to a newly created incomplete type. (It might be nice if this where forbidden by the language, but it isn't. so a conforming compiler can't just reject it.)

Comment: @Weather Vane: There's nothing to object here - your code is valid. However, `void foo(struct S *p) {} struct S* p = 0; int main() { foo(p); }` should trigger a diagnostic message, since these are two unrelated `struct S` types. MSVC does not complain, which is a bug in MSVC.

Comment: It would also be possible to put `struct ucred;` before the prototype, rather than moving the entire struct definition

Comment: Thanks, I know, but I ask how to supress it. If it's not possible, amen, but you've not replied to my exact question.

Comment: @realtebo I understand you were only interested in suppression but just like you I wasn't able to find an exact gcc flag to suppress just this warning.   Did you try `-Wno-missing-declarations` at all?  The gcc documentation says "No warnings are issued for global functions and variables without prior declaration."

Answer (score -1):

Add `-include ucred.h` to the GCC command line.

Alternately, create a new .c source file with these contents:

```
#include "ucred.h"
#include "misc.c" // <- name of the original .c file you were compiling
```

And compile that instead of the original .c file.

Comment: Usually gcc gives the name of the warning unless you use the -fno-diagnostics-show-option (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Diagnostic-Message-Formatting-Options.html) and I think you can enable th

Comment: Whoops posted too soon - was just going to suggest using -fdiagnostics-show-option to re-enable them

Comment: Thanks, I know, but I ask how to supress it. If it's not possible, amen, but you've not replied to my exact question.

Comment: If you do what I suggest, the warning message will no longer appear.  How is that not the same as suppressing it?

Comment: Why does the answer to move the struct declaration to before the function declaration have two up votes, while my answer, which is basically the same suggestion, just more specific about how to do that, have one down vote?